# Pricing Details For Einstein APIs?

Tags: api, integration, einstein

1. What are the pricing details for Einstein APIs? I read the following to  get more insight:

   - https://metamind.readme.io/v2/docs
   - https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis
2. Also specifically I wanted to build functionality around Sentiment API to perform sentiment Analysis for user feedback. What is the maximum text limit that we can pass as a parameter to these endpoints? I checked the documentation but I din't find anything about text limit.

   - https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/sentiment
   - https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/sync/analyzesentiment/v2

Answer (score 7):

From the [Rate Limits](https://metamind.readme.io/docs/rate-limits) documentation:

> Einstein Vision provides two tiers of usage: free and paid. Each tier gives you a specific number of prediction calls. These limits apply only to predictions. A prediction is any POST call to `/vision/predict` to pass in an image and receive a prediction. A prediction call includes both predictions made from custom classifiers and predictions made from the pre-built classifiers.
>
> ## FREE TIER
>
> When you sign up for an Einstein Platform Services account, you get 1,000 free predictions each calendar month. You get 1,000 predictions on the first of every month to be used by the last day of the month.
>
> When you exceed the maximum number of predictions for the current calendar month, you receive an error message when you call the /predict resource.
>
> ## PAID TIER
>
> If you need more predictions than are available in the free tier, you can purchase them. Purchased predictions are also provisioned on a calendar month basis.
>
> - **Heroku**—If you signed up for an account using the Heroku add-on, you can purchase more add-on credits. See the Einstein Vision add-on page for more information about plans and pricing.
> - **Salesforce**—If you signed up for an account using Salesforce, contact your account executive to purchase predictions for Einstein Vision. To add predictions to an existing account, you must provide the organization ID for your Einstein Platform account. To get your Einstein Platform organization ID, call the usage API. See GET API Usage.

I'm not sure how the Heroku pricing compares to the AE provided pricing. I don't have access to the AE pricing, but I can see the following in the Heroku pricing:

[image: Einstein IO pricing]

- Free - 1,000/Month
- $40/month - 10,000/Month
- $850/month - 250,000/Month
- $3400/month - 1,000,000/Month

I'm also not sure if or how this vision pricing translates to the language APIs.

Comment: Note that the Rate Limit seems to have been updated to 2000 free predictions (since checking in Winter '20), even though Heroku still shows only 1000 free/month